# Getting thumbnail from video url and loading on gridview very slow

Tags: android, gridview, video, adapter, thumbnails

I am getting the list of video url from the sdcard and passing to the adapter. In adapter, creating the thumbnail bitmap from the url of video. It became very slow to load the gridview and scrolling also very slow. Is there any ways to make it faster and easy to take the thumbnail from sd card.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = infalter.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgQueue = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgQueue);

            holder.imgQueueMultiSelected = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgQueueMultiSelected);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.imgQueue.setTag(position);

        try {

            Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(data.get(position).sdcardPaththumbvideo, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

            if (bitmap==null) {
                holder.imgQueue.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);
            }
            else{
                holder.imgQueue.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` off of the main application thread. In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoList), I used [the SmartImageView library](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view) to load the thumbnails asynchronously, applying my custom `VideoThumbnailImage` as a `ViewBinder` on my `SimpleCursorAdapter` showing the results of finding all videos:

```
  private static class ThumbnailBinder implements
      SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View v, Cursor c, int column) {
      if (column == c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)) {
        VideoThumbnailImage thumb=
            new VideoThumbnailImage(
                                    c.getInt(column),
                                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

        ((SmartImageView)v).setImage(thumb,
                                     R.drawable.ic_media_video_poster);

        return(true);
      }

      return(false);
    }
  }

  private static class VideoThumbnailImage implements SmartImage {
    private int videoId;
    private int thumbnailKind;

    VideoThumbnailImage(int videoId, int thumbnailKind) {
      this.videoId=videoId;
      this.thumbnailKind=thumbnailKind;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(Context ctxt) {
      return(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(ctxt.getContentResolver(),
                                                      videoId,
                                                      thumbnailKind,
                                                      null));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks CW, let me try this

Comment: After struggled I can able to maintain the cache for video thumbnail. Thanks a lot CW and thanks for given SmartImageView. Its really awesome